# Why can't i create a GPO to install a .msi to clients?

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, windows-server, gpo, windows-server-2019

(I am using a german Windows Server 2019, so bear with me. I try to translate everything to recognizable english ui equivalents)

The goal is to create a GPO to install a .msi file to client computers. Everytime I try to create the GPO, it says

```
Add operation failed. Unable to extract deployment information from the package. Run validation on the package to ensure that the package is correct.
```

The Windows Event Log outputs a warning and then an error(translated by me).

Warning:

```
Warning: Event 119, Software Installation
While reading the msi file \\dc1\gpo\Install\AnyDesk_Client_v2.msi, an unexpected error occured. The error is not severe enough to cancel the operation. The following error occured: The operation was completed successfully
```

Original german text:

```
Beim Lesen der MSI-Datei \\dc1\gpo\Install\AnyDesk_Client_v2.msi ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten. Der Fehler ist nicht schwerwiegend genug, um den Vorgang abzubrechen. Folgender Fehler ist aufgetreten: Der Vorgang wurde erfolgreich beendet.
```

Error:

```
Error: Event 103, Software Installation
The Software Installation could not deliver/prepare the package AnyDesk_Client_v2.msi. The following error occured: The directory name is invalid
```

Original german text:

```
Die Softwareinstallation konnte das Paket AnyDesk_Client_v2.msi nicht bereitstellen. Folgender Fehler ist aufgetreten: Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig.
```

What I tried:
Using another msi. Used the standard Anydesk.msi (so no "_" in the filename). I tried the Teams x64 .msi from [MS Teams MSI Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoftteams/msi-deployment). I tried a Futuremark_SystemInfo.msi I had
lying around.
I put all the files in \dc1\NETLOGON and tried again. I put all the files in \dc1\SYSVOL and tried again. I checked that authenticated users had access to the share. I logged on directly on the Domain Controller as Domain Admin via RDP. I logged directly on the Domain Controller via VMRC (it's a virtual environment). I checked if I can access the shares I put the .msi's in (I can). I got a tip that says

```
Go to Default Domain Controllers Policy
Expand Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Administrative Templates\System\Netlogon
Change the Netlogon and Sysvol Compatibility to enabled (2 seperate settings)
```

This does not work because there is no Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Administrative Templates - it is Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates. But there is no setting to enable NETLOGON/SYSVOL Compatibility underComputer Configuration\Administrative Templates. I assume this is a tip relating to an older Windows Server version.